# Getting error: "The content-type is not JSON compatible" after a period of time

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm not really sure exactly how long it takes before I get this error, but after a period of time, I get "The content-type is not JSON compatible" error. I am able the query just fine from graphql playground but not in my app. I am using persisted queries, so not sure if that is the cause.

The only fix is to restart my app.

Here is the
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TIyP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace you posted I can see that the server (in particular, probably the resolver for whatever query/mutation you are sending) is returning something unexpected i.e. not "JSON compatible".

Based on what you provided, that's all I can say. Please add more details and I can provide additional help. Just including the stacktrace is not enough to determine the cause of this issue.